# Cron on Rackspace Cloud using Codeigniter CLI

Tags: php, codeigniter, cron, rackspace-cloud

I am trying to run a cron using codeigniter CLI ... Rackspace cloud has a way to access scripts and you need to choose the script language, they have 4 options, perl, php etc.

To access command line you need to use perl. Now I created a file "test.sh" it looks like

```
#!/bin/sh
$ php /mnt/target03/12345/www.domain.com/web/content/index.php cron1 cron_test
```

when i run the cron, i get this

```
/mnt/target03/12345/www.domain.com/web/content/crons/test.sh:
line 2: command not found
/mnt/target03/361169/www.domain.com/web/content/crons/test.sh:
line 3: $: command not found
```

Does any of you has experience with running crons with rackspace cloud?

Comment: People at http://serverfault.com/ probably have a lot of experience with Rackspace.

Comment: You don't add the `$` to your shell file -- just start the line the `php`.